# how to retrieve the image value from the string array resource and use the value to set background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have written a program in android. In it I have added all my images in the drawable folder eg dress_1.png, dress_2. But image name dress_1 is added into the string-array resource. Now I don't have idea how to retrieve the images from this string-array resource and set as background into the imageview. I have mentioned following code. Please, help me to complete my task. I will really appricate you.Thank you in advance.
Summary: How to retrieve string value from an array-string into java and how to use retrieved string images from the drawable folder in android
xml file (small code)

```
              <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/T1C4R1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".45"
                    android:background="@drawable/rszjumper"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />
```

SecondActivity.java

```
        for (int c = 0; c < conditions.length; c++) {
            weatherCondition(conditions[c]);
        }
        private void weatherCondition(int c) {

        switch(c){
        case 5:
            String dress_array[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.five);
            weatherDress(dress_array);
        }

    }

    private void weatherDress(String[] dress_array) {
    for(int d =0; d < dress_array.length; d++ ){
        String img = "drawable/" + dress_array[d];

        T1C4R1.setBackground(img);
//img.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(image_string[1] , "drawable", getPackageName()));
        }

    }
```

string.xml

```
    <!-- condtion 5 -->
    <string-array name="five" >
        <item name="dress_2">dress_2</item>
        <item name="dress_8">dress_8</item>
        <item name="dress_6">dress_6</item>
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would look up the drawable based on its resource ID (`R.drawable.dress_1`, for example). If you're looking them up based on a string, you need to first find the resource ID based on the name.

```
public Drawable getDrawableByName(Context context, String name)
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", 
        context.getPackageName());
    return resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
}
T1C4R1.setImageDrawable(getDrawableByName(getContext(), "dress_2"));
```

Alternatively, you could simply return the resource ID and use `setImageResource` to assign the drawable based on its ID.

You should also note that your current structure will only display the last image in the array, since you are overwriting the drawable image with each pass in your loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. so result will like this T1C4R1.setBackground(getDrawableByName)? . Please, could you explain me little bit more how it will insert dynamically in java code

Comment: You would use `setImageDrawable`. (See [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html))

Comment: It is giving me some error T1C4R1.setImageDrawable(getDrawableByName(SecondActivity.this, "dress_2"));

Comment: Is `T1C4R1` initialized after the layout is inflated?